# Store additional information after authentication [Spring]

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

I am developing a web application that has the following requirements:

1. Allow the user to login
2. On the server side, the user is authenticated via a 3rd party REST web service.
3. The REST web service will return a unique token and key, if the authentication is successful.
4. Any subsequent requests to the REST web service must contain the token received in point 3 (above).

I am using spring-mvc and spring security for the web application. 
So, I got a solution working, however I'm new to spring and not sure if the solution is correct.

Can someone please advise if:

1. Is the solution correctly implemented?
2. Does the solution impact performance in any way?
3. Does the solution create any security holes?

Thanks :)

---

**Solution**:

1. I created a MyUser object that will store the additional information received from the REST service.

   ```
   public class MyUser implements Serializable {

       private static final long serialVersionUID = 5047510412099091708L;
       private String RestToken;
       private String RestKey;

       public String getRestToken() {
           return RestToken;
       }
       public void setRestToken(String restToken) {
           RestToken = restToken;
       }
       public String getRestKey() {
           return RestKey;
       }
       public void setRestKey(String restKey) {
           RestKey = restKey;
       }
   }
   ```
2. I then created a MyAuthenticationToken object that extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken. This object will be used in the CustomAuthenticationProvider (point 3 below).

   ```
   public class MyAuthenticationToken extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken {

           private static final long serialVersionUID = 7425814465946838862L;
           private MyUser myUser;

           public MyAuthenticationToken(Object principal, Object credentials, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities, MyUser myUser){

               super(principal, credentials, authorities);
               this.myUser = myUser;   
           }

           public MyUser getMyUser() {
               return myUser;
           }

           public void setMyUser(MyUser myUser) {
               this.myUser = myUser;
           }
       }
   ```
3. I created a custom authentication provider that will call the REST service for authentication and then store the additional information in the myUser and myAuthenticationToken objects.

   ```
   public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

           @Override
           public Authentication authenticate (Authentication authentication) {

               MyUser myUser = new MyUser();
               MyAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = null;
               String name = authentication.getName();
               String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

               //Just an example. This section will connect to a web service in order to authenticate the client
               if (name.equals("justh") && password.equals("123456")) {

                   //Set the Token and Key Received from the REST WebService
                   myUser.setRestKey("RestKey");
                   myUser.setRestToken("RestToken");

                   List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
                   grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));

                   authenticationToken = new MyAuthenticationToken(name, password, grantedAuths, myUser);

                   return authenticationToken;
               } else {
                   return null;
               }
           }
   ```
4. Finally, I can access the data stored in my controller

   ```
   public ModelAndView adminPage(Authentication authentication) {

           MyUser user = null;
           //Get the additional data stored
           if(authentication instanceof MyAuthenticationToken){
               user = ((MyAuthenticationToken)authentication).getMyUser();
           }

           ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
           model.addObject("title", "Spring Security Hello World");
           model.addObject("message", "This is protected page - Admin Page!" + authentication.getName() + user.getRestKey() + user.getRestToken());
           model.setViewName("admin");
           return model;
       }
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is the right one. You should implement a custom `AuthenticationManager` and `Authentication` whenever your requirements exceeds a simple username password authentication flow.

But don't forget to comply with [`AuthenticationManager`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationManager.html)'s interface contract.

I did something quite similar in my [webmailer](https://github.com/ksokol/minig/blob/fd45f30729e2e5c0929035f8c84b3285ae0524dd/minig/src/main/java/org/minig/security/MailAuthenticationProvider.java) for authenticating against an smtp/imap server with `javax.mail` and it works flawlessly.

Comment: Cool - thanks for the input. 
Will have a look at your code as well.